# Android Map rendering gets distorted and showing black below after changing visibility

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, android-mapview

I updated my google maps libraries from 9.4.0 something to latest versions and upgraded sdk for `Android 8.0`. But because of that multiple maps usage broke in the app. I did a work-around by making them `liteMode="true"` where they weren't required to be interactable. But one instance of where i cannot do so is causing problems. It seems to be working fine on older API phones and Simulators, but the issue comes on newer API.

I have a searchbar at the top, a search overlay opens with places listed when we tap on the searchbar. So what happens is when we go to the screen, you see everything normal as it should be, map on the whole screen and searchbar at top. But when you open the search (it programatically hides the mapLayout stack which contains the map and related text overlays with `setVisiblity(View.GONE)`) and select or cancel any option, it goes back to how it should be(it hides the search listing and unhides the maplayout stack). But only that the map isnt rendering correctly.

I can see that the MapView is fine, because i see the google logo where it should be, but the actual rendering of the map is distorted, like a rectangle who's bottom side is morphed towards up to some degrees. And the area below it is black.

[image: buggy map image]

Some additional info is that, the other cases where i fixed it with litemode is that if the map was inside a scrollview, the top of the map-rending would stick to the proper place, but the bottom would stick to the screen's middle or relative y-position (just outside the scrollview). While scrolling, i would see it distorting in height on scroll. So the issues seem related as the inside the view rendering is being bugged on scroll and on size and layout change.

I have already googled and tried many solutions like placing a transparent view in front of it, nesting it inside another linearLayout or turning off hardware acceleration etc... but none seem to work correctly. Also, i have tried both MapFragment and MapView as well. The result is the same.